Total charge within a sphere
Consider an electric field in free space with
$$
 \mathbf {D} = -3z\mathbf {a_r} μCb/m^2
$$
I need to calculate the total charge within a 3mm sphere centered at (0,1,1).
I calculate the charge desnisty as
$$ ρ_v= div\mathbf {D}$$
z in spherical coordinates equals to rcosθ so
$$  \mathbf{D} = -3rcosθ\mathbf {a_r} μCb/m^2 $$ and
$$ div\mathbf {D} = -9cosθ$$
Finally I integrate
$$ Q = \int ρ_vdV = \iiint r^2sin(θ)cos(θ)drdθdφ $$
The problem that I have is that the sphere is not centered at the origin so I have a hard time to find the integration limits. I also tried to use cartesian coordinates in order to place the origin of the coordinate system at the center of the sphere but it is getting to complicated.

Write D for the origin at (0,1,1).

Since the field is external to the sphere, it does not induce any total charge density in the sphere ($\rho_v = 0$), per Gauss's law.
You can see this with the integration you have set up as well, your limits only depend on your boundary's shape and size, not on the location
